# How to install Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

When I follow any tutorial video's and click the download link on Selenium it downloads Selenium as a jar file I'm not sure what to do with. In all the video's I see it downloads the file as an add-on to Firefox which is different to me. I have downloaded a separate add on for Firefox but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help or a pointer to a good tutorial would be great! thanks in advance. Sorry for the question I'm sure it's very basic I just can't figure it out.

[image: Selenium download page]

Comment: you're download selenium server (so a jar file) you might want to search google for 'download firefox selenium addon'

Comment: Can you point me to a good book or tutorial from there? I have installed plugins but there is no buttons or options in tools available to me. I have Selenium Button but it tells me I do not have Selenium IDE, however, I got the Selenium IDE add-on that Pedro below linked me to.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should look on the Selenium IDE site and follow the installation guide.

Comment: I have downloaded wrong thing. You should download Selenium IDE, but you have download Selenium Standalone Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Access this [url](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-expert-selenium-ide/).
2. Click on **Add to firefox**
3. Restart firefox

Comment: Thanks, that downloaded the extension but I can't see anywhere to access it. In tutorials it's normally in tools/selenium but I have nothing.

Comment: The extension should appears on the top of the browser

Comment: This was the extension that ended up working for me. Thank you though! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/?src=search

Comment: URL is out of date. As usual, the answer  does not include any useful information with dealing with this. Links are forever, right? Sure. Try this one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps:

1. Open Firefox -> Search Selenium IDE on Google
2. Go to this URL: **https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-expert-selenium-ide/**
3. Click on Add to firefox
4. After installation see message
5. Restart the Browser
6. GO to Tools-->Selenium IDE